How to compress or magnify part of the axis in ggplot2?
I have a new question following this one. I hope to compress part of the Y axis and magnify another part. I use the customed function magnify_trans, but get an error. The function and an example are:
> magnify_trans <- function(intercept, reducer) {
    trans <- function(x, i = intercept, r = reducer) {
      sapply(x, function(x) {
        if (x > i) x
        else x / r + i
      })
    }
    inv <- function(x, i = intercept, r = reducer) {
      sapply(x, function(x) {
        if(!is.na(x)) {
          if (x > i) x
          else (x - i) * r
        }
      })
    }
    trans_new(name = 'custom',
              transform = trans,
              inverse = inv)
}
>   ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-10, 30), y = c(0, 250)), aes(x, y)) +
+     stat_function(fun = function(x) 12 + 180 / (1 + exp(-.759*(x - 7.69))),
+                   size = 2,
+                   color = "yellow") +
+     coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 250))+
+     geom_abline(intercept = 44, slope = 0, lty = 2)+
+     scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5, 25)) +
+     coord_trans(y = magnify_trans(intercept = 44, reducer = 20))   
Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
Error in UseMethod("rescale") : 
  no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "list"

The magnify_trans function defines a new transformer. I try the generic transformer such as trans_exp(10) to substitute the magnify_trans function in the example, and it works well. Is there anything wrong in the customed function? My ggplot2 version is 3.5.0 and R version is 4.3.3.

My question has been solved by an AI tool. It substitutes the sapply function with a R base function ifelse.
magnify_trans <- function(intercept, reducer) {
      trans <- function(x, i = intercept, r = reducer) {
        ifelse(x > i, x, x / r + i)
      }
      inv <- function(x, i = intercept, r = reducer) {
        ifelse(!is.na(x), ifelse(x > i, x, (x - i) * r), NA)
      }
      trans_new(name = 'custom',
                transform = trans,
                inverse = inv)
      }

